# cannot convert from 'boost::interprocess::mapped_region' to 'boost::interprocess::mapped_region &&'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost

When I try to compile a simple boost application with

```
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
```

headers in **VS 2010**, I get the this error message.

```
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44_0\boost\interprocess\detail\move.hpp(342): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'boost::interprocess::mapped_region' to 'boost::interprocess::mapped_region &&'
1>          You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
1>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44_0\boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp(159) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::interprocess::mapped_region &&boost::interprocess::move<boost::interprocess::mapped_region&>(T)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::interprocess::mapped_region &
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44_0\boost\interprocess\detail\move.hpp(342): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object' to 'boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object &&'
1>          You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
1>          c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44_0\boost\interprocess\shared_memory_object.hpp(85) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object &&boost::interprocess::move<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object&>(T)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object &
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I couldn't understand what the problem. I deleted all the function implementations, there are only c_tor and d_tor but still the same error..

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this as shown [here](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/09/62542.php). It looks like a limitation in either Boost or the compiler in handling `rvalue` references.

> `#define BOOST_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES`
>   worked. Thanks.